# Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration::getFilterSchemaAssetsExpression()

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, vendor

I updated my vendors on symfony2, and after I began to got this error, I have no idea why it appears

> uan@juan-VirtualBox:/var/www/msw-web$ php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
>   PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration::getFilterSchemaAssetsExpression() in /var/www/msw-web/vendor/doctrine-migrations/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DiffCommand.php on line 85
>   PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/msw-web/app/console:0
>   PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/msw-web/app/console:22
>   PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/msw-web/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
>   PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/msw-web/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:75
>   PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /var/www/msw-web/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:194
>   PHP   6. Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle\Command\MigrationsDiffDoctrineCommand->execute() /var/www/msw-web/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:224
>   PHP   7. Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\DiffCommand->execute() /var/www/msw-web/vendor/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/Command/MigrationsDiffDoctrineCommand.php:46
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration::getFilterSchemaAssetsExpression() in /var/www/msw-web/vendor/doctrine-migrations/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DiffCommand.php on line 85
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0003     328524   1. {main}() /var/www/msw-web/app/console:0
>       0.0210    1930264   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/msw-web/app/console:22
>       0.0289    2110852   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/msw-web/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
>       0.1349    7697284   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/msw-web/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:75
>       0.1422    7697284   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /var/www/msw-web/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:194
>       0.1432    7697828   6. Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle\Command\MigrationsDiffDoctrineCommand->execute() /var/www/msw-web/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:224
>       0.1767   11022484   7. Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\DiffCommand->execute() /var/www/msw-web/vendor/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/Command/MigrationsDiffDoctrineCommand.php:46
>
> juan@juan-VirtualBox:/var/www/msw-web$

I am not sure if the problem came from Doctrine.

---

I tryed to update doctrine dbal, I used on mi file deps

```
doctrine-common
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.2.1

doctrine-dbal
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.2.1

doctrine
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.2.1
```

But I get the same error because when I reinstall vendor it download the version 2.1.X

What can I do?

Regards.

Comment: "Warning: Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension" -- Have you loaded the XDebug extension?

Comment: I don't know but no worries, I had that problem since I was created the project, my real problem right now is doctrine migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set commit version value in deps file

```
[doctrine-migrations]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/migrations.git
    version=b86b4cc0a39714f0aa53b908d495beacfa0e4011
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check which version of Doctrine/DBAL do you have. Probably you have incompatibile versions of DoctrineMigrations and DoctrineDBAL.

Method 'getFilterSchemaAssetsExpression` was added in 2.2 IIRC.
See that [commit](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/commit/d9f8cd1f7eb43a965eeb9ae7df33e55699831771)

Comment: [doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.1.4

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.1.6

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.1.6

Comment: Yeah you have dbal 2.1.6 but for your version of doctrine migration 2.2 is needed.